# Unable to get file path from URI in android 10 for some images only

Tags: android

My app needs an option to upload image file, which is perfectly working for some files only. I am unable to distinguish between the image files, and why it's not working for every images. I am debugging this app on my Android 10 phone.

The following code I have written to get the file path from URI.

```
try {
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
     document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
     cursor.close();

     cursor = getContentResolver().query(
              android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
              null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
     cursor.close();
     return path;
}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("GET PATH EXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

It throws **Index 0 requested, with a size of 0** exception

Comment: Use a library that can support alternative ways of uploading your content. For example, OkHttp/Retrofit can use [an `InputStreamRequestBody` implementation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196) that can use the `Uri`.

Comment: You have also check if `moveToFirst()` returns true

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, it worked!